# How can I split one Excel Worksheet into multiple files based on date column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need to split a worksheet with 10,000 rows into multiple Excel files based on the dates in column D. The file has 9 columns (A:I). Dates on column D are currently formatted as DD/MM/YYYY. I only want to split the file into MMM/YYYY so there are fewer files. Here is my code so far, it splits the worksheet into multiple files but when I open the files only the header has been copied over, not the data for relevant month & year.

How can I copy and paste all the data that's relevant to the MMM/YYYY in column D and how can I save all the split files into a specific folder like this one? C:\General\London\Clients

```
Sub SplitData()
'
' SplitData Macro

Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim nLastRow, nRow, nNextRow As Integer
Dim strColumnValue As String
Dim objDictionary As Object
Dim varColumnValues As Variant
Dim varColumnValue As Variant
Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim aCol As String
aCol = "D"

On Error GoTo err1

 With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.EnableEvents = False
 End With

Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

 For nRow = 1 To nLastRow

    strColumnValue = Format(objWorksheet.Range(aCol & nRow).Value, "Report_mmm_yyyy")

    If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
       objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
    End If
Next

varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys

For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)
    varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)


    Set objExcelWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add

    Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name

    objWorksheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy
    objSheet.Activate
    objSheet.Range("A1").Select
    objSheet.Paste

     For nRow = 1 To nLastRow
        If CStr(objWorksheet.Range(aCol & nRow).Value) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then

           objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).EntireRow.Copy

           nNextRow = objSheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
           objSheet.Range("A" & nNextRow).Select
           objSheet.Paste
           objSheet.Columns("A:I").AutoFit
        End If
    Next
    objExcelWorkbook.SaveAs (CStr(varColumnValue))
Next

err1:
     With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
     End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing was replacing

```
If CStr(objWorksheet.Range(aCol & nRow).Value) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then
```

with

```
If Format(objWorksheet.Range(aCol & nRow).Value, "Report_mmm_yyyy") = varColumnValue Then
```

But I made more changes in order to do the copy-pasting a bit quicker. As a side note, pasting is not a quick option, you could do something like `TargetCell.Value = SourceCell.Value` (in this case only values get transferred).

```
Sub SplitData()
  '
  ' SplitData Macro

  Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim nLastRow As Integer, nRow As Integer, nNextRow As Integer
  Dim strColumnValue As String
  Dim objDictionary As Object
  Dim varColumnValues As Variant
  Dim varColumnValue As Variant
  Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
  Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim i As Long

  Dim aCol As String
  aCol = "D"

  On Error GoTo err1

  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
  End With

  Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
  nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  For nRow = 2 To nLastRow

    strColumnValue = Format(objWorksheet.Range(aCol & nRow).Value, "Report_mmm_yyyy")

    If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
      objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
    End If
  Next

  varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys

  For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)
    varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)

    Set objExcelWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add

    Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name

    objSheet.Rows(1).Value = objWorksheet.Rows(1).Value
    objWorksheet.Rows(1).Copy objSheet.Rows(1)

    nNextRow = 2
    For nRow = 1 To nLastRow
      If Format(objWorksheet.Range(aCol & nRow).Value, "Report_mmm_yyyy") = varColumnValue Then
        objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).Copy objSheet.Rows(nNextRow)
        nNextRow = nNextRow + 1
      End If
    Next
    objSheet.Columns("A:I").AutoFit
    ' Closing the workbook with changes saved
    objExcelWorkbook.Close True, CStr(varColumnValue)

  Next

err1:
  With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .EnableEvents = True
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did the answer help to solve the problem? If so, please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sub SplitData()
  '
  ' SplitData Macro

Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim nLastRow As Integer, nRow As Integer, nNextRow As Integer
  Dim strColumnValue As String
  Dim objDictionary As Object
  Dim varColumnValues As Variant
  Dim varColumnValue As Variant
  Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
  Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim i As Long
  Dim FPath As String
  FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Dim aCol As String
  aCol = "A"

On Error GoTo err1

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
  End With

Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
  nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For nRow = 2 To nLastRow

```
strColumnValue = Format(objWorksheet.Range(aCol & nRow).Value, "mmm_yyyy")

If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
  objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
End If
```

Next

varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys

For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)
    varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)

```
Set objExcelWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add

Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name

objSheet.Rows(1).Value = objWorksheet.Rows(1).Value
objWorksheet.Rows(1).Copy objSheet.Rows(1)

nNextRow = 2
For nRow = 1 To nLastRow
  If Format(objWorksheet.Range(aCol & nRow).Value, "mmm_yyyy") = varColumnValue Then
    objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).Copy objSheet.Rows(nNextRow)
    nNextRow = nNextRow + 1
  End If
Next
objSheet.Columns("A:K").AutoFit
CheckDir (FPath & "\" & varColumnValue)
objExcelWorkbook.SaveAs FPath & "\" & varColumnValue & "\" & "Report.xlsx"
' Closing the workbook with changes saved
objExcelWorkbook.Close True, CStr(varColumnValue)
```

Next

err1:
  With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .EnableEvents = True
  End With

End Sub

Function CheckDir(Path As String)

```
If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir (Path)
End If
```

End Function